# Update a session variable and refresh page in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-4

I have several views where I want to be able to reference a date-based session variable called `session[:month_view]` which defines what data is pulled from various tables. My trouble is that I want the user to be able to update their views to look at the next month or the previous month and I cannot figure out how to update `session[:month_view]`.

I have a method for setting the session variable if it does not currently exists (effectively setting the `:month_view` to the current month:

In the controller, called `before`:

```
  def set_month_view
    if session[:month_view] == nil
        session[:month_view] = DateTime.new(Time.now.year, Time.now.month, 1, 0, 0, 0, "+00:00")
    end
  end
```

What I would like is a way of using a link or a form in my views to increment or decrement :month_view by 1 or -1. I am guess that I need to pass an integer to the `set_month_view` method, but I just don't know how to.

Comment: So ideally there would be the same link on lots of different pages, which would change the current month and then reload the page?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick and be quite easy to read/maintain.

Controller methods:
(Add redirects or renders as appropriate)

```
# Make sure this remains in before_filter for the increment and decrement methods too
def set_month_view
  session[:month_view] ||= DateTime.new(Time.now.year, Time.now.month, 1, 0, 0, 0, "+00:00")
end

def increment_month_view 
  session[:month_view] = session[:month_view] + 1.month
end

def decrement_month_view 
  session[:month_view] = session[:month_view] - 1.month
end
```

View links:

```
You are viewing month: <%= session[:month_view] %>
<%= link_to 'backwards', decrement_month_view_controller_path %>
<%= link_to 'forwards', increment_month_view_controller_path %>
```

Comment: Thanks Matt - I am getting: undefined local variable or method `decrement_month_view_controller_path' for #<#<Class:0x5ee49f8>:0x5eec0c0> on the view - is this actual syntax or a representation of another path?

Comment: You'll need to put the name of the controller or resource in place of `_controller_`, or replace the link with `<%= link_to 'forwards', {controller: NAME, action: decrement_view_path} %>` (replace NAME with the controller name). I suggest you read some [routing guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) to understand what this is doing.

Comment: OK - the controller is called StaticPages (or static_pages_controller.rb) and the decrement_month_view method is in that file. Still getting errors :( I have got this as the link code.... <%= link_to 'backwards', decrement_month_view_static_pages_path %>

Comment: Think I am almost there. I basically need to understand routes a lot better. Marking as answered.